# getting an exception 4.3 on an NSSound object

Tags: objective-c, xcode, exception, breakpoints, nssound

I load a sound like so:

```
sound = [[NSSound alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"alert" ofType:@"mp3"] byReference:NO];
```

Also I have "all exceptions" break point turned on in xCode. The above line throws an exception twice in a row before the code continues and my sound plays. all i see is that the code stops with Thread1: "breakpoint 4.3"

Could someone explain to me what's going on here and what 4.3 means? is there any reference for these numbers?

I've tried to use just:

```
sound = [NSSound soundNamed:@"alert"];
```

with exactly the same result...

thank you.

Comment: What happens if you turn off stop on exceptions? What is the error message?

Comment: when I turn off "all exceptions" I don't get any errors and all works fine. But what bugs me is that I don't know what this 4.3 exception means. As a matter of fact I can't find any information on the subject. I've seems 4.1 for instance which tells me nothing and I can't figure out this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are the first who noticed this problem with the System Sound…. I have the same issue in Xcode with the System Sound of the iPhone (iOS). If I turn on the "all exceptions" break point I get the same message you have. I went crazy today with this…. but probably is an Apple's issue and anyway is not dangerous maybe…..
Is there any way to disable this exception from "all exceptions" in Xcode?

… well if you enable exceptions only for "Objective-C" in the options, you do not get this message anymore. It mean that it is a C++ exception (more apple / framework related).